# How do I optimize iteration speed through 2 lists for a lookup value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists built from a "cursor.fetchall()" statement from two different data sources.

List 1's structure (when doing call to print()):

```
[(23026, ), (23038, ), (23039, ), (23040, ), (23041, )]
```

List 2's structure, seemingly truncated (when doing a print() statement):

```
[(23038, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
 (23039, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
 (23054, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0)]
```

I'm needing to look up each value in list_1 to see if it exists in list_2. And then, vice versa, in a separate task to see if each of the list_2[0] values are in list_1.

Example of what I'm currently using:

```
    # Loop Through Rows In A List
    for a in list_a:
        if a == None:
            break

        # Loop Through Rows In B List
        keep_item = False
        for b in list_b:
            # Check If Item From A Database Is Still In B Database
            if a[0] == b[0]:
                keep_item = True
                break

        if not keep_item:
            # Delete Item
            print("Deleting Item " + str(a[0]))
            items_deleted += 1
```

Each list contains roughly 30,000 records, and is currently very slow when using this method.

Is there a faster way to perform these lookups? I'm performing a SQL INSERT or DELETE for each iteration (if that matters).

Comment: `print` is no linger a statement in Python 3 - it's a function

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Comment: revised question fwiw... but not sure how helpful your comment is. Equivalent of me saying you spelled "longer" wrong...

Comment: To look up many values quickly, use a set or dict instead of a list. When that isn't appropriate (e.g., the keys can't be hashed), use a sorted list and `bisect`. Or, if you need to modify the list between searches, use a logarithmic data structure like a red-black tree, b-tree, skiplist, etc. (there are many options on PyPI).

Comment: I'll research sets. Is it possible to set the result of a "cursor.fetchall()" to a set or dict instead of a list? Not sure if helpful, but I do not modify either list when iterating.

Comment: create a set  `lookup_set = {x[0] for x in [(23038, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
 (23039, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
 (23054, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0)]}`, then you can use `a[0] in lookup_set` instead of a loop

Comment: @SourceMatters It's worth making comments like ForceBru's because otherwise, we can't guess whether the code is wrong (and we should give you a Python 3 answer) or the tag is wrong (and you actually need a Python 2 answer).

Comment: I guess.. I tagged it properly, code reflects it being used as a function, and when I typed it in the question, I used parentheses to denote it as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you've already got these values in a SQL database. Presumably with an appropriate index. So let the database do the work. Instead of reading all of A and all of B into memory, use a join or a subselect to read only those elements of A that have a match in B.

---

But let's assume that's not appropriate somehow.

To look up many values quickly, you usually want to use a set or dict instead of a list.

In your case, you're trying to look up values on `b[0]` rather than all of `b`, so that would be a dict, with your current `b[0]` as the keys. Instead of this:

```
lst2 = [(23038, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
        (23039, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
        (23054, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0)]
```

… you want this:

```
dct2 = {23038: ('Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
        23039: ('Foo', 'Bar', 0), 
        23054: ('Foo', 'Bar', 0)}
```

Ideally, you want to build the dict instead of the list in the first place. If you can't do that, you can convert in linear time:

```
dct2 = {b[0]: b[1:] for b in lst2}
```

Since you appear to be getting these from a database cursor: Most database libraries for Python have cursors that act as lazy iterators of rows (fetching a buffered chunk at a time in whatever way is most efficient), so you can just use the cursor itself:

```
dct2 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in cursor}
```

However you build your dict or set, lookups take constant time instead of linear—and they're simpler to write, to boot:

```
try:
    b = dct2[a[0]]
except KeyError:
    print("Deleting Item " + str(a[0]))
    items_deleted += 1
```

… or:

```
if a[0] not in dct2:
    print("Deleting Item " + str(a[0]))
    items_deleted += 1
```

No need for a loop and a `found` flag.

---

For many cases—although I don't think it will work here—you can make things even simpler. If you have two sets, or a set and a dict, and you just want the intersection of the first set with the second set, or with the dict's keys, that's just:

```
set1 & dct2
```

---

When a hash-based structure like a set or dict isn't appropriate (e.g., if the keys can't be hashed), you can still get logarithmic time—not quite as good as constant, but a lot better than linear. If you can just `sort` the list after building it, you can use `bisect` to search it. If you have to keep modifying the list between searches, you'll want to use a data structure that stays sorted—a balanced binary search tree, something wider like a b-tree, a hybrid b-tree/deque structure like `blist`, a skiplist, etc. There are many options on PyPI to choose from, and you can even more to implement yourself in a good book on data structures.

Comment: Thanks abarnert. Playing with the "cursor" code you posted to see if I can cobble something together with that. These come from two separate databases unfortunately, so a Join/SQL method won't work for me. For list 1, I'm using the same cursor statement, but using row[0] for both. Is that acceptable? Aiming to get them both as dictionaries.